# Dynamically embed Twitter timelines (API V 1.1)

Tags: api, twitter

Twitter's new embedded timelines don't seem to allow dynamic creation of embedded timelines.

Here is the section on their site:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

In older versions of the API, it was possible to switch the username in the widget dynamically, but the new API forces you to store the full widget on their servers and access via a widget id. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking this approach as well. This example was great to work from and learn how to use scala for this: http://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/using-twitter4j-with-scala-to-access-streaming-tweets/

Basically, by creating a twitter oauth app and using twitter4j, we created a client and styled it with javascript. We used regex with javascript to make the links and usernames hyperlinks.

Answer (score 4):

Nope :( Unfortunately, Twitter matches up all of the Widgets (embedded timelines are widgets) with their `id`s. As such, it recognizes your timeline widget's `id` and displays your timeline, thus you cannot simply change the Twitter handle that it queries.

Here are your options:

1. Create multiple widgets and show/hide them based on some event
2. Use AJAX and query a server-side script to grab a user's timeline.

For maximum flexibility, the second option is likely to be your best route. I can help you with that if you are using PHP or .NET, so let me know if you are (and which one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate the offer, but we're working with Scala/Play and were simply injecting the username into the widget dynamically. It works for now, but will not once the feeds are fully deprecated.

Comment: You're welcome, and I understand that you are using a different technology. However, if that is the case then you should have stated that in your original post. As it stands, this post is unlikely to be useful to any future users, as you have accepted an answer that has little to nothing to do with your original post. Were I able to do so, I would down-vote this question, for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

This works excellent for Timeline with the new Twitter API 1.1

1) Download twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar in http://twitter4j.org/en/
2) Try use this code:

```
private static final String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_SECRET_KEY)
    .setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
try {
    Query query = new Query("MrEdPanama");
    QueryResult result;
    do {
        result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        }
    } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
    System.exit(0);
} catch (TwitterException te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was asked months ago, but this can be achieved quite easily actually, by adding "data-" tags in your URL.

Check Twitter page for customization of the embedded timelines: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization

Comment: The question was about creating widgets where the username, etc. could be changed, which is *not* possible in the new system. In the new system, each widget must be created manually.

Comment: Nevermind; I see that this apparently does work for usernames. But note that it does not work for search queries. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, that indeed doesn't seem possible at the time. Twitter does allow the dynamic change of usernames, user ids, favorites and lists, which I believe was the question here. I might have misread though. In that case it doesn't work (yet)..